# How to format text wrapped inside specific symbols within a html structure and format it

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, cpu-word

I want to add an external script to a website so I can format how certain elements looks in order to make my life easier editing the content. I am wondering if there is a way to find a text that is wrapped between a hashtag and two dots within a paragraph and give it a specific format via css. Javascript, Jquery or Css would work, I just dont manage to find a solution yet.

The html structure is like this:

```
<p class="title">
::before
#home: research paper
</p>
```

And I would like to make it like this:

```
<p class="title">
::before
<span>#home:</span> research paper
</p>
```

Keeping in mind that the values of what's after the hashtags won't be always the same (although it will be always after the hashtag and before the two dots). It would be possible to search for specific words (example: #home: or #house) as I already know which words will be in the website and they wont change.

Could anyone point me in the right direction to do this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

css

```
.title span {
  /* css */
}
```

js

```
$(".title:contains('#home:')")
.html(function(_, text) {
  return text.replace(/(#+.*:)/, "<span>$1</span>" )
});
```

```js
$(".title:contains('#home:')")
.html(function(_, text) {
    return text.replace(/(#+.*:)/, "<span>$1</span>" )
})
```

```css
.title span {   
    color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="title">
::before
#home: research paper
</p>
```